# Changing a slider to a grid

Tags: theme-development, customization

I got sucked into helping a friend with her blog and got a bit over my head. I need to change the slider on the homepage of [this site](http://www.something-beachy.com/) to be a grid like [this site](http://weworewhat.com/). What would the easiest way to do this and how would I go about implementing it? I'm pretty familiar with Wordpress when it comes to making small changes but have never made a large change to a theme before.